# Yii2 GridView multidimensional array

Tags: php, arrays, gridview, yii2

I got array:

```
123 => [
    "2015-09-01" => ["sum"=>"1030","count"=>"4"],
    "2015-09-02" => ["sum"=>"10","count"=>"24"],
    "2015-09-03" => ["sum"=>"120","count"=>"34"],
    "2015-09-04" => ["sum"=>"200","count"=>"45"]
    ],
124 => [
    "2015-09-01" => ["sum"=>"132","count"=>"48"],
    "2015-09-02" => ["sum"=>"10","count"=>"24"],
    "2015-09-03" => ["sum"=>"120","count"=>"34"],
    "2015-09-04" => ["sum"=>"200","count"=>"45"]
    ],
```

Now i like display this in GridView to get table like this:

```
--------------------------------------------
| ID | 2015-09-01 | 2015-09-02 | 2015-09-03|
|    |-------------------------------------|
|    | sum  |count| sum |count | sum |count|
|------------------------------------------|
|123 |1030  | 4   | 10  | 24   |120  | 34  |
|------------------------------------------|
|124 |132   | 48  | 10  | 24   |120  | 34  |
--------------------------------------------
```

Question how to get such an effect ?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Do you have sample code of what you have tried that is not working?

Comment: Idon't think you can do this with the base yii2 gridview I think for this you need  an extension like this http://demos.krajee.com/grid-demo

Answer (score 1):

For a 2d array with numbered rows, each row containing an array of elements, the following implementation is quite trivial.

**1. Initialize the data provider**

First initialize the array data provider in your controller by passing the data in allModels parameter. mode details of ArrayDataProvider can be found [here](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-data-arraydataprovider)

```
$dataProvider = new ArrayDataProvider([
            'allModels'=> $your2darray,
            'pagination' => [
                'pageSize' => 10,
            ],
        ]);
```

**2. Display the Grid**

Assuming you have passed the above data provider variable, in your view , use it in the grid as below, specifying whatever column to be displayed.

```
<?= GridView::widget([
        'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
        'columns' => [
            ['class' => 'yii\grid\SerialColumn'],

            'id',
            'field1', 
             ...
            ['class' => 'yii\grid\ActionColumn'],
        ],
    ]); ?>
```